# Non-responding EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

In my activity , an EditText is invisible by default and once a button is clicked it becomes visible.

I managed to do that but once the EditText is visible ,  I can't input text to it.In other words, the soft keyboard never appears ,the writing cursor never appears , and the hint inside it never goes and it's like "frozen".

I tried the following but didn't solve my problem

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                editsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editsearch.setEnabled(true);
                editsearch.setFocusable(true);


            }
        });
```

and this is my xml

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Comment: could you please post your layout xml :)?

Comment: @ReneFerrari done

Answer (score 0):

Try adding editsearch.requestFocus() method to your code after the line editsearch.setFocusable(true).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I use relative layout and below my Edittext , there is a listview. I found that the Edittext was behind the listview so  I brought it to front.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                editsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editsearch.requestFocus();
                editsearch.bringToFront();
                editsearch.invalidate();

            }
        });
```